# How to add the two variables php

Tags: php

I got error here while adding these two variables.This is the code i have tried.

```
echo "<td id='submit_button'>
         <input type='submit' value='Proceed to Pay        (Rs.".$fare+$hot_fare.")' class='submit' onClick='return validation()' />
      </td>";
```

This is the error i got.

> ```
>  1600' />
> ```

But I actually need the total for two variables.

```
proceed to pay 4323
```

Comment: Try with value='Proceed to Pay        (Rs.".(int)$fare+(int)$hot_fare.")'

Comment: @Siva that will produce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the values inside `()` otherwise your summing strings:

```
echo "<td id='submit_button'>
         <input type='submit' value='Proceed to Pay        (Rs.".($fare+$hot_fare).")' class='submit' onClick='return validation()' />
      </td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put both variables in single variable i.e. `$total_fare= $fare+$hot_fare;` . 
 Like below

```
$total_fare= $fare+$hot_fare;

echo "<td id='submit_button'>
         <input type='submit' value='Proceed to Pay        (Rs.".$total_fare.")' class='submit' onClick='return validation()' />
      </td>";
```